# JQuery Datepicker does not position properly in Chrome with "body { overflow:scroll }"

Tags: css, google-chrome, jquery-ui-datepicker

JQuery Datepicker scrolls along with the page in Chrome. On click of the calendar icon datepicker appears right beside it, but when i scroll the page, it scrolls too, instead of sticking beside calendar icon. Datepicker's position is absolute and body has overflow: scroll. If i remove overflow on body then the datepicker position is fine. But i need scroll bar on my page.

In firefox, the calender comes somewhere at the bottom of the page. If I give body position as ’relative’, the calendar scroll issue is resolved. But this does not work for chrome.

How do i fix it? Any help/pointer would be greatly appreciated.

```
     body {
           overflow:scroll;
           width:100%;
           height:100%;
           padding:0;
           margin:0;}
    #datepicker{
           position: absolute;
           top: 1285px;
           left: 120.40625px;
           z-index: 1;
           display: block;}
```

Top and left are calculated by the jQuery plugin depending on the position of the calender icon on page.

Comment: Add `position:relative` to `#datepicker` parent element.

Comment: On giving position:relative to #datepicker, the calender moves to the bottom of the page in Chrome

Comment: Thats because you have a high `top` value. Change it.

Comment: As i have mentioned in the post, the Top and left values are automatically calculated by jQuery. Position:relative fixes the problem. But how to calculate the Top value dynamically as the position of calender on page is not consistent.